# EntityManager does not persist (silent fail) - Multiple DataSources

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm creating a Spring Boot project that will work as a library to be included in other Spring Boot apps.

When my project is included, I already get access to the "default" DataSource that has been configured in the "parent" project. I need this because my library operates on the client's database.

However, I also need to setup an additional DataSource that will be internal to my project, in an embedded H2 database.

I've tried the following setup:

**Configuration class**

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import tech.repo.Action;

@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "dbadmin.enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
@ComponentScan
@EnableConfigurationProperties(DbAdminProperties.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "internalEntityManagerFactory", 
    transactionManagerRef = "internalTransactionManager", 
    basePackages = { "tech.repo" }
)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DbAdminAutoConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    Environment env;
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource internalDataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder<?> dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:file:./dbadmin_internal");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("sa");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("password");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean internalEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(internalDataSource());
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("internal");
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("tech.repo");
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(properties);
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        
        return factoryBean;
    }
    
    
    
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager internalTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(internalEntityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
    
    
}
```

In the controller:

```
    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "internal")
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "internal")
    private EntityManager entityManager;
```

I've tried getting either the EntityManagerFactory or the EntityManager, based on the PersistenceUnit name, but in all cases when I call persist nothing is saved in the database:

```
@GetMapping
@Transactional("internalTransactionManager")
public String test() {
        Action a = new Action();
        a.setDescription("test");
//      entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager().persist(a);
        entityManager.persist(a);
        // Rest of the controller's code...
}
```

It seems some part of it is working, because the database tables in the package `tech.repo` get actually created at the start of the program on the "internal" (correct) DataSource. But when I persist nothing is saved. If I remove the @Transactional annotation it will generate an actual 500 error: `No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call`.

In the startup logs, I see that the string:

```
j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'internal'
```

appears multiple times, while only once for the 'default' persistence unit.

Comment: Do you get error while saving into database? Or it just silently executes this line and does nothing? Maybe turn on debug logs?